# Break yAxis & Errorbars

Tags: matlab, plot

You can download the .xlsx file from [HERE](http://cl.ly/3e291o2m1D2v/RSM_V_PSO.xlsx)

#### Code

```
figure('Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [100 100 800 375]);

RSM = xlsread('RSM_V_PSO.xlsx', 'Sheet1', 'C4:F103');
PSO = xlsread('RSM_V_PSO.xlsx', 'Sheet1', 'M4:P103');

ci_RSM = bootci(1000, @mean, RSM);
ci_PSO = bootci(1000, @mean, PSO);

Media_tot_RSM = mean(RSM,1)';
Media_tot_PSO = mean(PSO,1)';

ci_RSM = abs(ci_RSM' - repmat(Media_tot_RSM,1,2)) .* [1.9, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4; 1.9, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4]';
ci_PSO = abs(ci_PSO' - repmat(Media_tot_PSO,1,2));

ydata_m_RSM = (Media_tot_RSM');
ydata_m_PSO = (Media_tot_PSO');
xdata_m = [2 4 6 8];

[xData_RSM, yData_RSM] = prepareCurveData( xdata_m, ydata_m_RSM );
[xData_PSO, yData_PSO] = prepareCurveData( xdata_m, ydata_m_PSO );

hFit_RSM = plot(xData_RSM, yData_RSM,'.');
hold on
hFit_PSO = plot(xData_PSO, yData_PSO,'.');
hE_RSM   = errorbar(xdata_m, ydata_m_RSM, ci_RSM(:,1), ci_RSM(:,2));
hE_PSO   = errorbar(xdata_m, ydata_m_PSO, ci_PSO(:,1), ci_PSO(:,2));


hXLabel = xlabel('Objective function calls');
hYLabel = ylabel('Objective Function');

xlim([1 9]);
ylim([8.07 8.35]);

set(hFit_RSM                          , ...
'Color'           , [0 .2 .6]    );
set(hE_RSM                            , ...
'LineStyle'       , 'none'      , ...
'Marker'          , '.'         , ...
'Color'           , [0 .2 .6], ...
'markersize', 6);
set(hE_PSO                            , ...
'LineStyle'       , 'none'      , ...
'Marker'          , '.'         , ...
'Color'           , [.8 .3 .3], ...
'markersize', 6);

hLegend = legend([hE_RSM hE_PSO],'RSM Data \pm 95% CI', 'PSO Data \pm 95% CI', 'location', 'NorthEast' );
set(gca,'XTick',[2 4 6 8]);
```

#### Output:

[image: First]

then, using [BreakPlot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21864-breakplot) to break the yaxis give me this:

#### Code 2:

```
breakplot(xData_RSM,yData_RSM,8.095,8.335,'Line');
```

#### Output 2:[image: Second]

### Questions:

1. Is there any better way to perform this?
2. The errorbar `hE_RSM` vanish. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

*Alternative* - that takes a bit programming or work in the plot editor.

I usually place two axes for such a task, one for the top part and one for the lower part. I plot the same data in both of them, but then use axis to zoom in the correct range for both.
It takes a bit of tweaking to place them nicely and also turn of unnecessary legends.

Usually I also make a small third axis and draw two lines where the axe has been *cut*.